# codeigniter issue with num_rows (possible bug?)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im new to codeignitor and i have been having major issues with selecting queries. I originally thought it was me being a newbie (and maybe it is) but the fact that ive spent 3 days studying guides and videos im thinking its an issue.

When using this :

```
if ( $q->num_rows > 0 )
```

i continually get error:
**Trying to get property of non-object**

I'm following a guide to create a login authentication system. I'm clearly typing what the instructor has, but i cant get passed that error, and its not just this guide, other guides i have followed, has resulted in the same error when trying to grab row data.

Here is my model:

```
public function verify_user($email, $password)
{
$q = $this
        ->db
        ->where('email_address', $email)
        ->where('password', sha1($password))
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('users');

   if ( $q->num_rows > 0 ) {
        return $q->row();
       }
       return false;
}
```

Any help i could get on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
$q->num_rows
```

to

```
$q->num_rows()
```

See Here: [codeigniter guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Try doing:

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); //after $this->db ...... get('users');
```

to check your generated sql to see for any errors you have in your sql statement

Comment: changed it, now this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in /home/techf/public_html/application/models/admin_model.php on line 18

Comment: @bnelsonjax try doing echo $this->db->last_query(); after your get('users'); to check for any errors in your sql statement generated..

Comment: excellend idea on the last_query. i added that and commented out the num_row and it displayed correctly: SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `email_address` = 'me@aol.com' AND `password` = 'a36e1f2d2c1309e9f4c6d2ef75d01dd4fd21c' LIMIT 1

so its grabing the correct query, so why is num_rows not working?

Comment: ok im stupid, i was selecting the wrong table, it was 'users' and should ahve been 'admins'. but it was thanks to your idea with the last_query as I was able to run that into myphpadmin and it wasnt getting a result which lead me to discovering it was wrong table. thansk so much!

Comment: @bnelsonjax glad your figured it out.. :)

Comment: so used to the regular way of `num_rows` that I forgot CI made it in to a function. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use parenthesis after `num_rows`, because `num_rows` is a function (method), not a property:

`$q->num_rows()`

Also, if the query does not return any result, then `$q` will not be an object, but a boolean `FALSE`.

Suggestion:

```
public function verify_user($email, $password)
{
    $user = $this
        ->db
        ->where('email_address', $email)
        ->where('password', sha1($password))
        ->limit(1)
        ->get('users')
        ->row();

    return (empty($user) ? false : $user);
}
```

Comment: The function can be one-liner: `return $this->db->where('email_address', $email)->where('password', sha1($password))->limit(1)->get('users')->row();`

Answer (score 1):

Possible Reasons

its a function, Not a property. Change it to `$qry->num_rows()`

or

Your query is not successful and returns `FALSE`.

Try to `var_dump` your result first.

try this

```
if( $qry != FALSE && $qry->num_rows() > 0 )
```

//Query is success and there is at least one row.